# How to insert a python code in C++?

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, c++11, c++14

i am trying to embed a code python in c++. I have this python code :

```
#include <Python.h>

int main(int arg)
{
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\0");
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

but what i want is something like that :

## include

```
int main(int arg)
{
    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    int a = 5;
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("a = " + a);
    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

but it does not work. I mean i want with python to display the value of the variable a.
Thank you :)

Comment: look up sprintf()

Answer (score 2):

You could use [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) to convert your `int` to a string and then use [std::string::c_str](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) to get a temporary `const char*` to the internal data for the duration of the function call:

```
PyRun_SimpleString(("a = " + std::to_string(a)).c_str());
```

Comment: In contrast to any `sprintf` suggestions, `std::to_string` is a C++ solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to use correct C syntax in the C code; in C, `"a = "+a` does *not* concatenate strings (as you might assume), but calculate a useless pointer that points `a` bytes behind the start of the constant string `"a = "`. With `a` being `5`, there is nothing useful at that place.

Concatenating strings is not that straightforward in C; you need to handle preparing memory for the target, etc.; same for converting a number to a string. For example:
`char buffer[30];

 sprintf(buffer,"a = %d\n",a);`
and then
`PyRun_SimpleString(buffer);`

Comment: Ok so what is the "correct syntax" ? I thought to use , a instead of +a ?